# Pyramid under virtualenv: can't import simplejson module

Tags: python, pyramid

When I use the usual Python console, the import works well, but when I run `pserve` (Pyramid server) I get an error:

```
No module named simplejson
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably created your virtualenv without site-packages. Run `pip install simplejson` from your virtualenv to install the package.

Comment: Yes, pyramid documentation says `virtualenv --no-site-packages env`

Comment: @VitaliPonomar, as you should. `--no-site-packages` has become the default starting with `virtualenv 1.7` [(Source)](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv#changes-news).

Comment: I've just added simplejson through easy_install and it's OK. The same problem with PIL, but easy_install PIL didn't help this time... It installed PIL successful, but can't load in python scripts.

Comment: @VitaliPonomar: Perhaps it's better to open a separate question for that problem. Since running easy_install *did* resolve your original problem, it probably does not have the same underlying cause.

Comment: To get PIL installed via easy_install do "easy_install Pillow".. Pillow is a fork of PIL that is friendlier to automated installers.